# Perl regex: Extract values after hypen and before backslash

Tags: regex, perl

I have input data in the following format:

```
ABCD-ABCD
ABCD-ABCD/EFGH-1
ABCD-ABCD/EFGH-1/IJKL-9
ABCD-ABCD/EFGH-1/IJKL-9/MNOP-432
ABCD-ABCD/EFGH-1/IJKL-9/MNOP-432/QRST-C20-Blatt-4
```

I want to extract the below values values from the above.

```
ABCD
ABCD,1
ABCD,1,9
ABCD,1,9,432
ABCD,1,9,432,C20-Blatt-4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
(?:\/?[A-Z]+-([^\/\n]+))
```

See [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mG0uM9/1).

This will work if you have homogenous input data.

[Sample Perl code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMOUxLMmh4QjJhaWc):

```
$str = "ABCD-ABCD/EFGH-1/IJKL-9/MNOP-432/QRST-C20-Blatt-4";
@myarray = ($str =~ /(?:\/?[A-Z]+-([^\/\n]+))/g);
print join(",", @myarray) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
ABCD,1,9,432,C20-Blatt-4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-([^\/]*)
```

Use this regex.

```
print join(",", "ABCD-ABCD/EFGH-1/IJKL-9/MNOP-432/QRST-C20-Blatt-4" =~ /-([^\/]*)/g);
```